# How to submit Form data from PHP via mamp to Google spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-api-php-client

I am struggling to find out why it's able to send some data but not others. It submits 'email' and 'password' and 'id'... and just doesn't post 'sex' and 'dob'... I've been staring at it for the past several days.

```js
function doPost(e){ //this doPost(e) function on my app script app is able to allow interaction between my php and my app script app 
  var error = null;
  if(typeof e.parameter.action == 'undefined'){
    error = "action parameter required";
  }

  else if(e.parameter.action == "CRUD"){ //CREATE RECORD PROCCESS - the updateRecord() function is able to create record on a row with corresponding email.
      var result = updateRecord(e.parameter.email.trim(), e.parameter.password.trim(), e.parameter.id.trim(), e.parameter.sex.trim(), e.parameter.date.trim(), e.parameter.dob.trim());
  }
```

following is the function which is called by doPost(e) on my app script, and then proceeds to do Update or Create new record if an email does not exist... by basically appending to the spreadsheet.

```js
function updateRecord(email, password, id, sex, date, dob) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mySheet = sheet.getSheetByName("profiledata");
  var lastRow = mySheet.getLastRow();

  var ar = [email,password,id,sex,date,dob];
  var newRecord = [email,password,id,sex,date,dob];
  var range = mySheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1);
  var check = range.createTextFinder(email).findNext(); // this line of code checks the row and gets data by email
  var status;
  if (check) {
    check.offset(0, 0, 1, ar.length).setValues([ar]);
   // status = 'Record Updated';
    return {
      status: "success",
      message: "Record Updated"
    }
  } 
  else {
    range.offset(lastRow - 1, 0, 1, ar.length).setValues([newRecord]);
   // status = 'New Record created';
    return {
      status: "success",
      message: "New Record created"
    }
  }
}
```

Following is my PHP insert file... post.php... which is able to send form data toward the above doPost(e) function, which in turn runs updateRecord() function

```php
$url = "App script URL "; //this is where I pasted the URL of my app script


  $postData = [
    "action" => "CRUD",
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "password" => $_POST['password'],
    "id" => $_POST['id'], // "ignore this Comment!!" I create an id separately and echo it into the html form input as readonly.
    "sex" => $_POST['sex'],
    "date" => $_POST['date'],
    "dob" => $_POST['dob'],
  ];


  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, [
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
  ]);
  
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $result = json_decode($result, 1);


if($result['status'] == "success"){
      $returnmsg =  $result['message'];
     $_SESSION['success'] = $returnmsg;
     header("location: table.php?=success $returnmsg");
  }else{
     $_SESSION['error'] = $result['message'];
     $errormsg =  $result['message'];
     header("location: table.php?=err$errormsg");
  }
```

Below is my HTML form

```html
      <form method="post" action="post.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="on">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">password Field</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="this is a place for password" autocomplete="on">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id">id Field</label>
          <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $id;?>" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sex"> Gender Field</label>
          <input type="text" name="sex" class="form-control" placeholder="this is a place for gender" autocomplete="on">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dob">Date of Birth Field</label>
          <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="this is a place for DOB" autocomplete="on">
        </div>


        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

my problem is that this process is only able to send data to the spreadsheet but only up to 'id'... it doesn't submit 'sex' and 'date'

I searched all over google's documentation, and other places, I am coming up with nothing...

Comment: The Apps Script side of the code looks correct (apart form the fact that ar and newRecord contain undefined variables ). You need to implement logs to understand where the error occurs. E.g. log all parameters at the beginning of function updateRecord to see if the parameters have been posted correctly at all. If so, - log ar and check, otherwise implement logs within your PHP function - e.g. $postData.

Comment: It looks that the question needs more focus. Apparently you problem is on the PHP side... you should review how the HTTP Post request is done.